SLURM slurmschd.log - extreme big file size
one of the SLURM log files is slurmschd.log and in my case has a size of some hundreds of Gb. Is there a way to clean it and with this reduce its size - without break slurm? If I go somehow to clean it, am I go to loose some useful data?
Thanks

The slurmschd.log file contains the logs of the scheduling process inside Slurm. It only contains historical data and is not needed for other purposes than reviewing what happened and how priorities were computed for past jobs.
The path of the file is defined by the SlurmSchedLogFile configuration option. Its verbosity is controlled by the SlurmSchedLogLevel parameter. If you set its value to 0, the file should not grow anymore. You can then (compress and archive it and then) delete it.
